# Keep on getting the same error when I try to upload an image on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, file-upload, httprequest

I'm trying to upload an Image on Xamarin Forms but I keep on getting the error: an error occurred whilst sending a request. The code that I am using for my upload is:

```cs
try
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()), "\"file\"", $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");

    var uploadUrl = "{url}/api/files/upload";

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();                               

    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadUrl, content);

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    var response = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

and the code that is at the server is like the one below:

```cs
[Route("api/files/upload")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Post()
{
    try
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var fileName = postedFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                return "/Uploads/" + fileName;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return exception.Message;
    }

    return "no files";

}
```

But, upon uploading, before even reaching the server, I'm getting the error: an error occurred whilst sending a request. Anyone to assist me, I have searched for the error all over But no one has actually solved this error. Can someone assist me?

Comment: you need to look at the exception object and get the details of the exception, particularly the `InnerException` property

Comment: Where are you running your application? Android? iOS? Uwp? Android may require internet access permission. The httpClient for iOS can be changed from the project Settings. Try changing the tls settings before sending the request

Comment: hi @JuanSturla, I am running the Android Version but the error keeps on recurring. Let me try changing the TLS settings as you suggest... But how do I do so?

Comment: Hi @Jason.. Let me check and revert back to you

Comment: For uploading images it's best to upload them as base64. In this way you will send it as a string. Try that instead of using MultiFormDataContent

Comment: Does your `uploadUrl` really start with `{url}` or have you redacted the full URL for privacy?

Comment: if you intended to use string interpolation, you're missing the "$" here: `"{url}/api/files/upload"` should be `$"{url}/api/files/upload"`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the image size
Try uploading an image smaller than 2 MB
If it works, put this code in the web.config file in server to download larger images

```
 <system.web>
  
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
     
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
      <security>
          <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000"></requestLimits>
          </requestFiltering>
      </security>
</system.webServer>
```